# Confidence Interval for the product of heads and tails in 100 coin flips

Tags: probability, combinatorics, statistics, binomial-distribution, confidence-interval

If I flip 100 fair coins and then multiply the number of heads by the number of tails. Can you give a double-sided 95% confidence interval on the product of the number of heads by the number of tails? Let $T$ denote the number of tails, and let $P$ denote the product. So $P = T(100-T)$. I am trying to apply the central limit theorem. I already calculated that $E[P] = E[100T] - E[T^2] = 5000 - 2525 = 2475$. Is there a faster way to calculate the variance of $P$ other than brute forcing the value of $E[T^3]$ and $E[T^4]$? I am on the wrong track?

Comment: What is 'confidence interval' of a random variable?

Comment: The central limit theorem is not particularly useful here.  You have a discrete distribution on some integers up to $2500$ with the maximum probability at $2499$

Comment: @Henry, why should the CLT not be useful?  We apply it to justify a normal approximation for the Binomial distribution, which is also discrete and has bounded support.  Finite second moments and iid data are enough to employ classical CLT.

Comment: @StubbornAtom, I agree! The notion of "CI" for an observable RV doesn't make much sense to me either. I assumed OP's question  was asking for (approximate) quantiles of the distribution of the RV instead.

Comment: @Golden_Ratio - It gives a bad interval (either far too high or far too low) in this case, because of the desire for two tails for the product causes issues with the discreteness of the product at the top end and this does not work well when using a continuous approximation.  And unless you use a non-linear transformation, the distribution of the product is highly skewed never getting anywhere near a normal distribution

Comment: @Henry, I see, thanks for pointing out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the quantiles of the asymptotic distribution. In $n$ fair flips, we know by CLT that $$2\sqrt n \left(\frac{T}{n}-\frac{1}{2}\right)\underset{d}{\rightarrow}N(0,1),$$

so by the continuous mapping theorem,

$$\left[2\sqrt n \left(\frac{T}{n}-\frac{1}{2}\right)\right]^2=-\frac{4}{n}\left[T(n-T)-\frac{n^2}{4}\right]\underset{d}{\rightarrow}\chi^2_1\\
\implies T(n-T)\sim \frac{n}{4}\left(n-\chi^2_1\right).
$$

Thus, one possible construction of a $95\%$ CI is

$$\left[\frac{n}{4}\left(n-q_{0.975}\right),\frac{n}{4}\left(n-q_{0.025}\right)\right],$$

where $q_p$ denotes the $p$ quantile of $\chi^2_1.$ In your case, this would work out to

$$\left[\frac{100}{4}\left(100-5.02\right),\frac{100}{4}\left(100-0.001\right)\right]=[2374.5,2499.975]. $$

---

Remarks:

1. Note the mean is $\frac{n}{4}(n-1),$ which in your case is $\frac{100\times 99}{4}=2,475,$ as you obtained.
2. I assume the above is what you mean by "95% confidence interval for $T(n-T),$" i.e. an interval spanning $95\%$ of its distribution. However, I think we typically construct a CI for an unknown parameter. Presumably, in this experiment, the number of tails $T$ is observable and and hence $T(n-T)$ is computable so it seems a bit strange to call this a CI. What would make more sense to me is computing a CI for the probability weight of the coin, but the coin is known to be fair here.

Comment: The product has a discrete distribution (it can only take some integer values) and the probability of being above $2499.975$ (i.e. of being exactly $2500$) is about $0.08$, so your interval does not contain $95\%$ of the probability

Comment: @Haochen Li, CLT says if $X_i$ are i.i.d with mean $\mu$ and variance $\sigma^2$, then $\frac{\sqrt n}{\sigma}(\bar X-\mu)$ is asymptotically $N(0,1)$, which is how I have written it: $T/n$ is the sample average of iid Bernoullis, each with mean $1/2$ and variance $1/4$.

Comment: @Haochen Li, I still think $T(n-T)$ is observable.  If you toss the coin 100 times, you will know exactly how many times it came up tails; $T$ is your data.  True that the quantity is a random variable, but not an unknown *parameter*.  Just think about how you construct an ordinary confidence interval for, say, a population mean---we use the sample average (a stochastic but observable quantity) to do so.  However, we don't construct a CI for the sample average itself.

Comment: @Henry, it is indeed discrete; however, I am using an asymptotic approximation.

Comment: @Golden_Ratio - you may need a lot more than $100$ flips to deal with the issue at the top end - perhaps ten times as many

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using a computer, you might as well use symbolic computing (*Mathematica*):

```
g = TransformedDistribution[u (100 - u), 
   u \[Distributed] BinomialDistribution[100, .5]];

Mean[g]
```

(* 2475 *)

```
Quantile[g, .975]
```

(* 2500 *)

```
Quantile[g, .025]
```

(* 2379 *)

Comment: For a $95\%$ confidence interval, I guess technically you'd want the $0.025$ and $0.975$ quantiles

Comment: Your interval $[2379,2500]$ covers about $97.9\%$ of the probability and is in effect a one-sided interval, since $2500$ is the maximum possible value of $x(100-x)$